# What do you call work or tasks that are Not part of the main(highest priorty) work that a person is doing at the present time?

Tags: phrases, expressions, terminology

What do you call work or tasks that are Not part of the main(highest priority) work that a person is doing at the present time?

In lexico.com ,there is a term called side work:

( Credited reference: https://www.lexico.com/definition/side_work )

> side work
> Pronunciation /ˈsʌɪd wəːk/
> noun
> 1 historical A fortification or other defensive structure protecting the side of a position, body of troops, etc. Later only in plural. Compare "flanker".
> 2 Additional or subsidiary work; specifically (informal, in a restaurant, etc.) tasks such as setting tables, polishing silverware, etc., carried out by waiting staff in addition to their main work of serving customers.
> Origin: Mid 17th century. From side + work.

**Update:**

To elaborate on the nature of the work that I'm assigned, it's essentially like having to climb a ladder in order to re-plaster and repaint the walls inside a house,

- and as a byproduct of re-plastering and repainting said walls, there will be dust and dirt that falls on the floor
- the dust and dirt that falls on the floor need to be ultimately cleaned up
- However, the highest is re-plastering and repainting said walls
- the prudent step is to tactfully clean up as much dust and dirt as possible whenever I come down the ladder
- because it will be too cumbersome and too overwhelming to clean the dust and dirt on the floor when all the re-plastering and repainting said walls is complete.

( I suppose another way of phrasing it is that I'm trying to incidentally  clean up as much dust and dirt as possible whenever I come down the ladder )

But could someone please answer with a word/phrase/expression/saying that is more sophisticated and/or elegant?

Comment: *Additional duties* is an accepted term. But you need to be a lot more specific. Please describe the context and provide a sample sentence where the term would be used.

Comment: Is this work that's paid by your main employer, or something you do on the side for extra work (I guess *side hustle* might not be high class enough for you)? Is it the same or similar to your main work, or distinct? Is it like when you're a university professor but have to spend lots of time filling forms and writing grant proposals, a firefighter who gives presentations on fire safety when nothing's ablaze, or like an actor who waits tables, or a school art teacher who also sells a few paintings, or a politician who writes books in their spare time?

Comment: @StuartF  Please see my update on the question posting.

Comment: @PhilSweet  Please see my update on the question posting.

Comment: @YosefBaskin  Please see my update on the question posting.

Comment: *side task* is the phrase that comes to my mind.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes that type of work is referred to as "[housekeeping](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/housekeeping)" -- i.e., "tasks that need to be done as a regular part of your work but are not the main purpose of your work."

Comment: Hello, 452. I can't see a sense/subsense at M-W (please attribute correctly) that applies reasonably accurately.

Answer (score 1):

In the work that the OP describes, the cleanup is a task that must ultimately be performed.

Here, it can be seen as a **concurrent task**, i.e. it can be executed at the same time as other tasks.

This is a term from project management and scheduling in general.

However, there are other areas of management that have different lexicons, including the **non-promotable task**, as in this article in the Harvard Business Review: https://hbr.org/2022/04/are-you-taking-on-too-many-non-promotable-tasks